# Angular 5 HTTP request in intervals using Observables while value may change

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, angular5

how can I implement this correctly so it only subscribes to the latest value given? - it worked fine for me using simple setInterval, but I want to switch to Observables to better understand it.

problem is obviously that I subscribe twice and if I complete the subscribe to the function it's still going to fire the interval subscribe and I can't complete it, because I need it's intervals..

This is the component where I call the data (cityName can change depending on user input all the time and therefore change the request that is being made by http

```
submitData2(cityName) {
Observable.timer(0, 10000)
.takeWhile(() => this.alive) // only fires when component is alive
.subscribe(() => {

  this._weatherService.getWeather(cityName)
  .subscribe(weathers => {
     this.weathers = weathers;

    console.log(weathers);
    this.currentImg();
  },
     err => {console.log(err)},
     () => {console.log('end')}

);

});
 }
```

This is the service that makes the request depending on city name:

```
  getWeather(city): Observable<any[]> {
return this.http.get('weather/getCity/' + city)
  .map(res => res.json())     ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sub;
submitData2(cityName) {
if (sub) sub.unsubscribe();

sub =
   Observable.timer(0, 10000)
    .takeWhile(() => this.alive) // only fires when component is alive
    .switchMap(() => this._weatherService.getWeather(cityName))
    .subscribe(weathers => {
       this.weathers = weathers;
      console.log(weathers);
      this.currentImg();
    },
    err => {console.log(err)},
    () => {console.log('end')};
 }
```

this will work but you need to save your subscription outside of the function call so that you can clean it up if it is called again. If you don't want it cleaned up and want to keep all calls around until the takeWhile completes then you can remove that code.

Comment: Actually I want to change my answer a little.  If this._weatherService.getWeather is an http call that will complete the stream and not a continuous stream then I would use exhaustMap instead of switchMap.  This is to protect against network calls taking longer than 10 seconds to respond and unsubscribing from getWeather too early.